# CORS Origin Request not allowed

Tags: ajax, rest, api, cors, slim

I have an API written with Slim Framework. The API is giving me all the correct json responses but I'm struggling to make ajax requests as the browser blocks my requests saying that **no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**. I've written a respone method based on Slim's default and It looks like this:

```
public function withCustomJson($meta = null, $data = null)
    {
        if (isset($data)) {
            $finalResponse['data'] = $data;
        }

        $finalResponse['meta'] = array(
            'status' => (isset($meta['status']) ? $meta['status'] : null),
            //'message' => (isset($meta['message']) ? $meta['message'] : null),
            'message' => (isset($meta['message']) ? mb_convert_encoding($meta['message'], "UTF-8", "auto") : null),
            //'responseStatus' => (isset(self::$messages[$statusData['codStatus']]) ? self::$messages[$statusData['codStatus']] : null)
        );

        $response = $this->withBody(new Body(fopen('php://temp', 'r+')));
        $response->body->write($json = json_encode($finalResponse));

        // Ensure that the json encoding passed successfully
        if ($json === false) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(json_last_error_msg(), json_last_error());
        }

        $responseWithJson = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization');
        if (isset($meta['codStatus'])) {
            return $responseWithJson->withStatus($meta['codStatus']);
        }
        return $responseWithJson;
    }
```

Here's my base functiton for ajax requests:

```
function ajaxRequest(verb, endpoint, headers = null, body = null, async = true) {
    try {
        //Animação do loading
        $('body').waitMe({
            effect: 'facebook',
            text: 'Carregando...',
            waitTime: 8000
        });

        return $.ajax({
            ContentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'http://api.mydonmain.com.br/' + endpoint,
            type: verb,
            async: async,
            headers: {
                'xAuthChaveApi': localStorage.xAuthChaveApi,
                'xAuthCambistaID': cambistaLocal !== null ? cambistaLocal.id : null,
                'xAuthCambistaToken': cambistaLocal !== null ? cambistaLocal.sessao[0].token : null
            },
            data: body,
            error: function (error) {
                notificar(Status.SERVER_ERR);
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                if (headers !== null) {
                    for (var key in headers) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
                    }
                }
            },
            // complete: function() {
            //     $('#content').waitMe('hide');
            // }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        notificar(error);
    }

}
```

Even though I'm setting the **response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')** I'm not getting the header on the response therefore the problem remains.

Comment: For starters, you are sending more/different headers with your AJAX request, than you allowed for with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. If that's not it already, then you are probably not handling the preflight request correctly.

Comment: I've removed the allowed headers especification but It didn't solve my problem. I'm sorry for my ignorance but what would be handle the preflight correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser starts a CORS preflight check via the `OPTIONS` http method. 
Try to add this middleware and give me a feedback.

```
// CORS preflight middleware
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {
    if ($request->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS' || php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
        return $next($request, $response);
    }
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Method'));
    $response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->getHeaderLine('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```